# Who shot first at Dunning's mansion?

Tags: plot-explanation, red

In the movie *RED*, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_(2010_film)#Plot), when surrounded by FBI agents,

> The terminally ill Joe pretends to be Frank, walks outside, and is
>  killed by sniper from the Vice President's personal hit squad.

I watched that scene again and did not find anywhere a hint about the shooter. Is this explained somewhere else?

Comment: The film is 8 years old.  You don't need to worry about spoilers.

Comment: @Tim: my children just watched it today - it was brand new for them (as are many 5-20 years old ones)

Comment: @Tim Spoilers don't really have a shelf life.